# Duplicate published content to another language

Tags: 7, views

I have a big question without a solution, but I can't believe it doesn't exist.
I have a site in Portuguese and one in Spanish, I want to pass the contents of "pt" to "es", how would I do it without having to download the images and upload again manually? There are 400 more items and I would stay another 6 days just doing this.
I already tried going through the "Content", "Updates Options" below the filter list, but didn't get a good result. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

I have a website, this website has three versions, "Portuguese", "Spanish" and "English". All versions, although different, are managed by "Taxonomy", and "Content Types" to differentiate them.
There is a "Content Type" which is a photo gallery, such as a field and text, that text field needs to be translated into the other languages. However, some photos I needed to upload again, that is, I downloaded the photos, translated the text field and saved marking Spanish, but it was so time consuming and tiring. I would need to duplicate these fields, so translating them would greatly dominate the time spent.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) It's a little bit unclear what you are asking for. With items I guess you mean nodes. And you have a lot of PT nodes. Normally, when PT is the original language of a node and you add a new ES translation all fields are prefilled with the PT content. We also don't know if you are using [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) on your site. Maybe you can update your question for clarification. Because depending on your setup the necessary code may look pretty different.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I edited my comment because I could not post as an answer.